# When I run localserver on googleappengine error is "File "~/dev_appserver.py", line 102, in <module> assert sys.version_info[0] == 2 AssertionError"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu, anaconda, google-app-engine-python

I think that this problem is due to the python version. I used Anaconda with python 3.6 for learning django. Now I've to work on google app engine using python2.7. I uninstalled anaconda. Now when i run "python" I get:
"Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58)".
Is there a way to default back to python2.7?

I'm on ubuntu 16.04

edit: problem is not due to python version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Anaconda, you can create a new virtual environment by typing:

> conda install -n yourenvname [package]

So with python2.7 installed:

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
source activate python2
```

And if you want to leave the virtual environment:

```
source deactivate python2
```

If you want to list all of your virtual environment:

```
conda env list
```

This way, it will not interfere with your existing python 3.6.
Be aware of these command are used for **conda**, another command **pip** is for another case.

Answer (score 0):

To change to python2.7, you can use the following command in terminal

```
 alias python=python2.7
```

or

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7
```

For more detail https://askubuntu.com/questions/590027/how-to-set-python-3-as-default-interpreter-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks for i was able to change the default version of python. But my main problem is still there. That error still persist when I run localserver. Any more ideas...?

Comment: @DivyanshuSingh if answer is helpful or right then please accept

Comment: As I said my main problem is still there.

Answer (score -1):

For those who are using Windows and still facing the same issue, the easiest way is to remove all the other python versions except version 2.7x.